# PowerShellを実行する際に右クリックで「PowerShellの実行」したとき処理が実行されない。

Tags: powershell

下記をPowerShellにコピペで実行したときは問題なくスクリプトが実行されます。
★の間を入れるとpowershellで実行した場合に処理されることなく画面が落ちます。
●でpauseを入れても止まることなく落ちます。

```
$TargetLogFolder = "C:\copy"
★
if(-not (Test-Path $TargetLogFolder)){
    Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("ファイルが存在していません。","注意","OK","Warning","button3")
　　pause●
    EXIT
}
★
$g = "C:\hoge"
$o = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
New-Item $g\"$o.txt"
```

Comment: 「実行されない」とはどういうことでしょうか？ 具体的に説明してください。再現コードはもっと絞り込めると思います。`if`が真でありながら中のブロックが実行されないのか、それとも`if`が意図しない判定をされているのかで原因が異なってきます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
if文ですが$TargetLogFolderが存在していた場合は★の間は抜けて次の処理にいくように作成しています。(コピペしてpowershellで実行した場合は問題なく抜けます。)逆にフォルダがないとエラーが出ます。
しかし以下のように「pause」を
★
if (-not (Test-Path $TargetLogFolder)){
    Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("ファイルが存在していません。","注意","OK","Warning","button3")
pause←●にいれても止まらずに画面が一瞬だけ立ち上がり落ちます。
    EXIT
}
★
●を設定した後にpowershellで実行をした場合は止まることなく上記の記載となります。

Comment: コメントで説明するのではなく質問文を編集してください。また質問と関係ないコードを減らしてください。

Comment: 発生条件に`if`文は必要なのですか？ `pause` を１行上に移動した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
1行上にもっていっても事象はかわりませんでした。
if文は必要になります。ここは本来はサーバ上のパスを指定しますが、現在はローカルパスにしています。

Comment: ifが必要とのことなので、else句を足して意図しない分岐結果となっていないかは確認済みですか？

Answer (score 1):

この質問に関しては解決させることができました。 解決方法はスクリプト本体の保存を「UTF-8」から「ANSI」にしてpowershellの実行を行うことで正常に動作をすることを確認いたしました